# How to compare more than one row vector to a matrix?

Tags: matlab, vector, equality

I have a `24 x 3 matrix` `“point1”` and I have also 5 other `1x3 row vectors`. What I want is to compare all of the 5 different row vectors to each row of `“point1”` so as to see if any of the 5 vectors have a corresponding row in `“point1”` which is equal to them, and then return the index of that row in `“point1”`. I have been able to do this with the following code, but i am seeking a more simple and elegant (possibly without a loop?) solution.

```
point1 = [7.5   4   5
          8.5   4   5
         9.5    4   5
         10.5   4   5
         11.5   4   5
         7      4   5.5
         12     4   5.5
         6.5    4   6
        12.5    4   6
           6    4   6.5
          13    4   6.5
         5.5    4   7
        13.5    4   7
           5    4   7.5
          14    4   7.5
           5    4   8.5
          14    4   8.5
           5    4   9.5
          14    4   9.5
           5    4   10.5
          14    4   10.5
           5    4   11.5
          14    4   11.5
         5.5    4   12];

fN = [8, 4.5, 5];
fS = [8, 3.5, 5];
fE = [8.5, 4, 5];     
bN = [7, 4.5, 5];  
bT = [7, 4, 5.5];

for ii = 1:size(point1, 1)         
 indx(ii) = isequal(point1(ii,:),fN(:)') | isequal(point1(ii,:),fS(:)') | isequal(point1(ii,:),fE(:)') | isequal(point1(ii,:),bN(:)') | isequal(point1(ii,:),bT(:)') 
 pIndx = find(indx)      
end
```

This returns:

```
pIndx = [2 6];
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`ismember` with the `'rows'` flag](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to search for intersections between your vectors and your data matrix.

Using the above example it's probably easiest to [concatenate](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html) your query vectors into one matrix and use that as an input:

```
test = find(ismember(point1, vertcat(fN, fS, fE, bN, bT), 'rows'))
```

Which returns:

```
test =

     2
     6
```

Alternatively you can make the queries individually if the individual results are important:

```
test_fN = find(ismember(point1, fN, 'rows'));
test_fS = find(ismember(point1, fS, 'rows'));
test_fE = find(ismember(point1, fE, 'rows'));
test_bN = find(ismember(point1, bN, 'rows'));
test_bT = find(ismember(point1, bT, 'rows'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
[find(all(fN == point1, 2)), ...
find(all(fS == point1, 2)), ...
find(all(fE == point1, 2)), ...
find(all(bN == point1, 2)), ...
find(all(bT == point1, 2))]
```